# Automorphisms of manifold vs automorphisms of Hodge structure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold. Let $H^k = H^k_{prim} (X)$ be primitive cohomology of $X$ considered as an object in category of of polarized Hodge structures. We have a map
\begin{equation*}
h_k: Aut (X) \rightarrow Aut(H^k) 
\end{equation*}
**Question 1** Does $h_k$ have to be surjective for $k \neq 0, n$?

For boundary cases it obviously fails. You can not act non-trivially on $H^0$ via manifold automorphism. But $-1$ is a automorphism of Hodge structure.

**Question 2** Do you know about some analogous statements which are theorems? Could you give source for them?

Answer (score 1):

The homomorphism $h_k: Aut(X) \to Aut(H^k_{prim}(X,\mathbb C))$ is extremely interesting. Let me follow your notation and write $H^k$ for $H^k_{prim}(X,\mathbb C)$. Also, I will content myself to algebraic varieties in the discussion below.

Let me answer your first question. For a large class of varieties, the answer to your question is no.  Indeed, the ``general" variety has no non-trivial automorphisms to start with. On the other hand, as you said, there is always the automorphism $-1$ of $H^k$. For example, the general cubic threefold $X$ has no non-trivial automorphisms (so $Aut(X) = \{id_X\}$), whereas $H^3$ is a $10$-dimensional polarized Hodge structure. Thus $h_3$ is not surjective in this case.

As you see, the surjectivity of $h_k$ fails quite often.  It does hold in the case of complex tori as pointed out below in the comments.

To answer question 2 partially, let me point out that there is much work done on the kernel of $h_k$. These results (and the methods employed in their proof) might help you find the sort of statement you're looking for. Indeed, if $X$ is a curve of genus at least two, a principally polarized abelian variety, a hypersurface of degree at least three (and dimension at least two), a variety with very ample canonical bundle, or a hyperkahler variety with certain properties, then $h_k$ is injective; see  Section 2.5 (especially Prop. 2.15) in http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02249 .

Comment: Is not $h_1$ surjective for elliptic curves? Your elliptic curve is just $H^1(E, \mathbb{C}) / (H^{1, 0}(E, \mathbb{C})+H^1(E, \mathbb{Z}) ) $.

Comment: Also it seems impossible that automorphism group of Hodge structure is $GL_d( \mathbb{Z})$. You can consider case of elliptic curves. Action of $SL_2 ( \mathbb{Z})$ do not preserves Hodge structure. Each matrix, wich preserves Hodge structure is diagonal in basis $dz$, $d \bar{z}$. But there are a lot of unipotent matrices in $SL_2 (\mathbb{Z})$. This argument can be generalized for general Hodge structure as requirement on automorphism to have special sizes of Jordan blocks.

Comment: @quinque you're right. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Also you wrote "Thus $h_3$ is not surjective in this case, and it's not just because there is −1 acting on $H^3$. " Are you shure that there are other automorphisms of this Hodge structure? Why?

Comment: What I actually proved in comments about complex tori is that $h_1$ is surjection. $h_2$ does not have to be surjection. See my answer.

Comment: @quinque I'm not sure if there are   automorphisms (besides -1) of the intermediate Jacobian of a cubic threefold which don't come from the cubic threefold itself. Do you think that for a cubic threefold $X$, we have $Aut(X) x \{\pm id\} = Aut(J_X)$?

Comment: I do not know. The problem is that moduli space of cubic threefold is a quotient of 10 dimensional ball. But dimension of period domain is 25 (if I am not mistaking). So generic cubic threefold does not have generic Hodge structure of type 5 5 (by the way, generic Hodge structure indeed has just $\pm 1$ automorphism). There is 16 dimensional subspace in period domain, which corresponds to Hodge structure with automorphism group large then $\pm 1$. And I do not how to verify is the image in this subspace.

Comment: @quinque Thank you for your comment. I think the period domain is 15-dimensional (as the intermediate Jacobian is 5-dimensional); see p. 11 of http://www.math.ens.fr/~debarre/Periods-MSRInotes2.pdf

Comment: Thank you. 25 is dimension of grassmanian. 15 is dimension of isotropic grassmanian.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, I found counterexample even for complex tori. Denote the elliptic curve $\mathbb{C} / < 1, \lambda > $ by $E_{ \lambda }$. Consider complex tori $E_{\lambda_1} \times E_{\lambda_2}$. Moreover suppose that

- $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are generic i.e.  automorphism group $E_{\lambda_1}$ and $E_{\lambda_2}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z}$.
- $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are generic with respect to each other. It means that $\lambda_1 \notin \mathbb{Q} (\lambda_2)$ and $\lambda_2 \notin \mathbb{Q} (\lambda_1)$.

**Lemma** $Aut(E_{\lambda_1} \times E_{\lambda_2}) = \mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/ 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Let me use lemma to prove that for $E_{\lambda_1} \times E_{\lambda_2}$ map $h_2$ is not surjection. Notice that

$$H^2 (E_{\lambda_1} \times E_{\lambda_2}) = \Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_1}) \oplus H^1 (E_{\lambda_2}) \big)=$$ $$=\Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_1})) \oplus \Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_2}) \big) \oplus  H^1 (E_{\lambda_1}) \otimes H^1 (E_{\lambda_2}) $$

$\Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_1})) \oplus \Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_2}))$ has type $\begin{matrix} 0 & 2 & 0 \end{matrix}$. If you pass to primitive cohomology you have to take quotient by Kahler class $\omega \in \Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_1})) \oplus \Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_2}))$.

Easy to see from Lemma that $Aut(E_{\lambda_1} \times E_{\lambda_2})$ acts on $\Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_1})) \oplus \Lambda^2 \big( H^1 (E_{\lambda_2}))$ trivially. But this substructure has $-1$ automorphism which can be continued on hole $H^2$ by acting identity on another summand. So, I contacted automorphism of $H^2$ wich do not come from $Aut(E_{\lambda_1} \times E_{\lambda_2})$.

Proof of lemma.

Each automorphism of complex tori $\mathbb{C}^2 / \Lambda$ can be lifted to automorphism of universal covering $\mathbb{C}^2$, which maps lattice $\Lambda$ to itself. Let prove that in our case this automorphism is given by diagonal matrix. Suppose that $(1, 0) \in \Lambda$ maps to $(x, y) \in \Lambda$ and $y 
\neq 0$. Then $(\lambda_1, 0) \in \Lambda$  maps to $(\lambda_1 x, \lambda_1 y ) \in \Lambda$.

$$(x, y) \in \Lambda \Rightarrow  y \in \mathbb{Q}(\lambda_2)$$
$$(\lambda_1 x, \lambda_1 y ) \in \Lambda \Rightarrow  \lambda_1 y \in \mathbb{Q}(\lambda_2)$$

Then $\lambda_1 \in \mathbb{Q}(\lambda_2)$. It contradicts assumption of generic $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ with respect to each other.